# Modifying a field of a JSON object in Ballerina

Tags: ballerina

I have a requirement to:

1. read a JSON object from a file.
2. modify a single field in the json object.
3. write it back to the file.

My code looks like this:

```
json packageJson = check io:fileReadJson(packageJsonPath);
packageJson.'version = newVersion;
```

When I try to assign a new value to the `version` field, I get the following error:

```
invalid operation: type 'json' does not support field access for assignment
```

I thought of converting the json to a user-defined type, but this action needs to be performed on multiple json files and the structure of the json is not quite fixed (even though all files will contain the `version` field).

Is there a way to work around this? Or is there a different way to approach this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ballerina "type 'json' does not support field access for assignment"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64321335/ballerina-type-json-does-not-support-field-access-for-assignment)

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, converting to a user-defined type is not an option for me in this scenario. Also, that question is referring to Ballerina 1.2.x whereas I am on Ballerina Swanlake. I think the casting syntax might be different from the second part of the answer. The accepted answer here is the best solution imo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json` is the union `() | boolean | int | float | decimal | string | json[] | map<json>`. So a `json` value may be a non-JSON object value too. Before attempting to use the value as a JSON object, the type needs to be narrowed down to `map<json>` which represents JSON objects. Moreover, as with any map update, member access needs to be used to update the map.

```
map<json> packageJsonObj = check packageJson.ensureType();
packageJsonObj["version"] = newVersion;
```

or

```
if packageJson is map<json> {
    packageJson["version"] = newVersion;
} else {
    // handle the non-JSON object scenario
}
```

You can find more details in

- [JSON examples](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/#json)
- [Ballerina’s JSON type and lax static typing](https://medium.com/ballerina-techblog/ballerinas-json-type-and-lax-static-typing-3b952f6add01)